# Criar procedure SQL SERVER

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

Boa tarde a todos! :)

Sou nova em programação e estou com algumas dificuldades

Estou tentando cria uma procedure para atualizar a coluna Cli_TotalCompras, com o valor total já gasto pelo cliente. Ou seja, com o valor total das compras já realizadas, por cada cliente.

Já fiz o select, e peguei o valor total por cada cliente. Porém não consegui criar a procedure para inserir esse valor na coluna Cli_TotalCompras.

Alguém poderia me dar um exemplo, de como consigo resolver esse problema?

Eu acho que a minha lógica está correta (fazer o select desse valor total do primeiro cliente, fazer um insert na coluna Cli_TotalCompras desse primeiro cliente e depois disso fazer esses passos do segundo cliente até o último através de um loop), porém não consigo reproduzir no código.

Agradeço a todos que puderem me auxiliar!

```
create procedure sp_Cli_TotalCompras
@cli_id int,
as
begin
select c.cli_id, sum(vp.vpr_valorunit)
from vendaProduto vp inner join venda v on vp.ven_ID = v.ven_ID
inner join cliente c on v.cli_ID = c.cli_ID
where c.cli_ID = @cli_id
group by c.cli_id
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Basta juntar os dois comandos, pode ser feito assim:

```
INSERT INTO NomeDaTabela (cli_id, Cli_TotalCompras)
SELECT c.cli_id, SUM(vp.vpr_valorunit) Cli_TotalCompras
  FROM vendaProduto vp inner join venda v on vp.ven_ID = v.ven_ID
 INNER join cliente c on v.cli_ID = c.cli_ID
 WHERE c.cli_ID = @cli_id
 GROUP by c.cli_id
```

Basta colocar o nome correto da tabela e também o campo com o id do cliente, e demais campos que precisa no INSERT

Como é uma procedure, outra forma seria armazenar a soma numa variável e usar depois:

```
DECLARE @soma float
SET @soma = (SELECT SUM(vp.vpr_valorunit) 
  FROM vendaProduto vp inner join venda v on vp.ven_ID = v.ven_ID
 INNER join cliente c on v.cli_ID = c.cli_ID
 WHERE c.cli_ID = @cli_id
 GROUP by c.cli_id)

INSERT INTO NomeDaTabela (cli_id, Cli_TotalCompras) VALUES (@cli_id, @soma)
```

Neste caso, defina o tipo da variável igual ao tipo do campo no INSERT, aqui usei float para exemplificar, mas poderia ser decimal ou outro tipo.